# How to solve the binary classification problem

Tags: java, jvm, xgboost

I can use xgboost to solve the binary classification problem, but in java I can only get two-dimensional arrays of float type

```
Booster booster = XGBoost.loadModel(Objects.requireNonNull(modelStream));
DMatrix dmat = new DMatrix(s, nrow, ncol, missing);
float[][] predict = booster.predict(dmat);
```

This is my code using java, could someone help me?
Thanks